# How to open a form in access to edit from on click event?

Tags: ms-access, vba, vbscript

I got a main form which contains two coloumns which list a no/product. I had given vba code for product field click event to open preduct detail form with the selected product and it details to edit. I given code as below

```
Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    stLinkCriteria = Me.Product

    stDocName = "ProductDetail"
    DoCmd.openform stDocName, , , "Product = " & stLinkCriteria
```

When I click the product its showing a input box and while enter the value its opening the product details with correct information.

I dont want to input the product name every time. I want this to work directly while clicking the product and should open it product details.

Please let me know how can do this ?

Comment: Please post the record source for Product Detail. If the record source is a table, please post the schema for the table, if it is a query, please post the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If the [Product] field is text data type, enclose `stLinkCriteria` with quotes in your `OpenForm` statement.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , "Product = '" & stLinkCriteria & "'"
```

Comment: its still showing up the input box, thank you for the response

Comment: Does the record source for `ProductDetail` include a field named `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

This code help me to fix the above problem

```
Forms!Frm.SetFocus 

Const FORMNAME = "frm1"


Dim ctrl As Control
Dim strCriteria As String

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Set ctrl = Me.ActiveControl

strCriteria = "[Product] = """ & ctrl & """"


DoCmd.OpenForm FORMNAME, WhereCondition:=strCriteria

Exit_Here:
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
Resume Exit_Here
```